# How can I start application by package name from preferences screen with xml only

Tags: android, android-xml

I am working with preferences activity and I want to be able to tap a preference to start application without using java code.

Something like this:

```
  <Preference
    android:title="Tap me to start settings app"
    android:key="prefSettings"
    />
```

So when I click it a new app with known package name will open.

Please notice: I want to be able to do this without java code, xml only.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but pretty limited and I can't think of any use-case for this since you don't know if the *"target application"* exists (at least you can't check it via XML).

Here's the code:

```
<Preference
    android:key="my_key"
    android:summary="@string/my_summary"
    android:title="@string/my_title">
    <intent
        android:targetPackage="package.of.other.app"
        android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:targetClass="package.of.other.app.class"
    />
</Preference>
```